# Trouble to calculate count of all table records count as total

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have tried through to write sql using  sub query i had achieved count(*) of my table but as we know sub query takes alot of cardinality db resources i want my count(*) count as a column show
let suppose
my table have total 6 records and when i calculate count(*) of my table it will be show as:

```
6
6
6
6
6
6
```

I want to achieve such record as above mentioned without subquery.

```
WITH survey AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                student_id,
                performance,
                teacher_behaviour,
                syllabus,
                shift_incharge_behaviour,
                punctuality,
                teaching_status,
                voice_clarity_class,
                daily_class,
                exams_status,
                mtm_helpline_status,
                fee_dept_status,
                personality_status,
                madni_task_assessment,
                survey_id
            FROM
                survey_feedback
            WHERE
                survey_id = 1
            GROUP BY
                student_id,
                performance,
                teacher_behaviour,
                syllabus,
                shift_incharge_behaviour,
                punctuality,
                teaching_status,
                voice_clarity_class,
                daily_class,
                exams_status,
                mtm_helpline_status,
                fee_dept_status,
                personality_status,
                madni_task_assessment,
                survey_id
        ) UNPIVOT ( star
            FOR q
        IN ( performance AS 'PERFORMANCE',
             teacher_behaviour AS 'TEACHER_BEHAVIOUR',
             syllabus AS 'SYLLABUS',
             shift_incharge_behaviour AS 'SHIFT_INCHARGE_BEHAVIOUR',
             punctuality AS 'PUNCTUALITY',
             teaching_status AS 'TEACHING_STATUS',
             voice_clarity_class AS 'VOICE_CLARITY_CLASS',
             daily_class AS 'DAILY_CLASS',
             exams_status AS 'EXAMS_STATUS',
             mtm_helpline_status AS 'MTM_HELPLINE_STATUS',
             fee_dept_status AS 'FEE_DEPT_STATUS',
             personality_status AS 'PERSONALITY_STATUS',
             madni_task_assessment AS 'MADNI_TASK_ASSESSMENT' ) )
    ORDER BY
        1,
        2
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    survey PIVOT (
        COUNT ( student_id )
        FOR star
        IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )
    )
ORDER BY
    q;

I want such desire Result as below is the picture.Total column is the sum of total records of my table
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnn0u.png)

Comment: Could you boil down your example to a table with 5 rows and 3 columns, provide a sample data and expected result? You'll get 1) much better feedback and 2) possible find the solution yourself.

Comment: i have shared expected result image which has achieved through subquery.Now image has attached but i want to get count(*) of my table count without subquery.Thanks @MarmiteBomber